# How to get id of particular item of listview in android?

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I am using `Listview` and set the multiple item and each item have Like, share and comment option.
       Actually I have fetch the Item Id and also `setText` of `TextView`, Its Successfully. But Not able to get Item Id on Like Button Click event for particular item.
       How to fetch Item Id for every items in `Listview` on `Button` Click Event?

Demo for MyAdapter Class:

```
public class Adapter1 extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arr = null;
    Context context = null;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = null;
    HashMap<String, String> getData = new HashMap<String, String>();

    String urlLike = null;
    TextView strId = null;

    public NewsFeedAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arr) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arr= arr;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arr.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arr.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.my_list_item, null);
            /** initialize ViewHolder */
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            /** Initialize Widgets */
            /** Imageview */

            viewHolder.imgLike = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgLike);
            viewHolder.imgLike.setOnClickListener(this);

            viewHolder.imgComments = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgComments);
            viewHolder.imgComments.setOnClickListener(this);

            viewHolder.imgShare = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgShare);
            viewHolder.imgShare.setOnClickListener(this);

            /** TextView */
            viewHolder.txtId = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtId);

            viewHolder.txtDescription = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);

            getData = arr.get(position);
            viewHolder.txtId.setText(getData
                    .get(Fragment1.TAG_ID));

            viewHolder.txtDescription.setText(getData
                    .get(Fragment1.TAG_MESSAGE));

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    /** ViewHolder Class */
    public class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imgLike = null, imgComments = null,
                imgShare = null;
        TextView txtId = null,txtDescription = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.imgLike:
            strId = ((TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtId));
            System.out.println("On Click====="
                    + strId.getText().toString());

            urlLike = "http://www.example.com?id="
                    + strId.getText().toString() + "&user_id="
                    + myDetail.getUserId();

            new sendLikeData().execute();

            break;
        case R.id.imgComments:

            break;
        case R.id.imgShare:

            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    public class sendLikeData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(urlLike, ServiceHandler.GET);
            Log.d("Response : Like", ">" + jsonStr);

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        };
    }
}
OutPut is, NullPointer Exception in System.out.println("On Click====="
                        + strId.getText().toString());.
```

[image]

xml file is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/masterLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/five_dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/ten_dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/ten_dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDescription"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/ten_dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/ten_dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/ten_dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgImage"
        android:background="@drawable/strip"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgLike"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
                android:src="@drawable/like" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgLike"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgLike"
                android:background="@drawable/getbg"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/two_dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/ten_sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgComments"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
                android:src="@drawable/comments" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgComments"
                android:background="@drawable/getbg"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/two_dp"
                android:text="+1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/ten_sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgShare"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
                android:src="@drawable/share" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/ten_dp"
        android:text="id"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And Logcat is,

```
11-24 18:54:20.354: E/AndroidRuntime(7120): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
11-24 18:54:20.354: E/AndroidRuntime(7120):     Adapter.onClick(Fragment.java:342)
11-24 18:54:20.354: E/AndroidRuntime(7120):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4562)
11-24 18:54:20.354: E/AndroidRuntime(7120):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18918)
11-24 18:54:20.354: E/AndroidRuntime(7120):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
11-24 18:54:20.354: E/AndroidRuntime(7120):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
11-24 18:54:20.354: E/AndroidRuntime(7120):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
11-24 18:54:20.354: E/AndroidRuntime(7120):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5388)
11-24 18:54:20.354: E/AndroidRuntime(7120):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-24 18:54:20.354: E/AndroidRuntime(7120):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-24 18:54:20.354: E/AndroidRuntime(7120):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-24 18:54:20.354: E/AndroidRuntime(7120):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:655)
11-24 18:54:20.354: E/AndroidRuntime(7120):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView....

Comment: remove the implementation of onclicklistener and write separate view listener for every view it will work. i checked sample code it self...

Comment: @Pratt  TextView strId = (TextView) (((TextView) view.getParent()).findViewById(R.id.txtId));
            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!strId==="+strId.getText().toString());

Comment: @Pratt this line is Put in imgLike Button Click event.

Comment: @sri Yes this is error whrn using TextView strId = (TextView) (((TextView) view.getParent()).findViewById(R.id.txtId)); System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!strId==="+strId.getText().toString());

Comment: @sri Please suggest me and send me demo for write separate view listener for every view.

Comment: @Reena from where you getting that id? from your "arr"??

Comment: use this way viewHolder.imgLike.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(activity, "title"+arr.get(position).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   }
  });

Comment: @Reena see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with below code:

```
public class Adapter1 extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arr = null;
    Context context = null;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = null;
    HashMap<String, String> getData = new HashMap<String, String>();

    String urlLike = null;
    TextView strId = null;

    public NewsFeedAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arr) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arr= arr;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arr.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arr.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.my_list_item, null);
            /** initialize ViewHolder */
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            /** Initialize Widgets */
            /** Imageview */

            viewHolder.imgLike = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgLike);


            viewHolder.imgComments = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgComments);
            viewHolder.imgComments.setOnClickListener(this);

            viewHolder.imgShare = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgShare);
            viewHolder.imgShare.setOnClickListener(this);

            /** TextView */
            viewHolder.txtId = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtId);

            viewHolder.txtDescription = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);

            getData = arr.get(position);
            viewHolder.txtId.setText(getData
                    .get(Fragment1.TAG_ID));

            viewHolder.txtDescription.setText(getData
                    .get(Fragment1.TAG_MESSAGE));

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               

            }
        });

         viewHolder.imgLike.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               
                strId=arr.get(position).getId();//or whatever you want to do do here.
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    /** ViewHolder Class */
    public class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imgLike = null, imgComments = null,
                imgShare = null;
        TextView txtId = null,txtDescription = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: not fetch the getId(); in strId=arr.get(position).getId();

Comment: @Reena my office time is over now, you can send me source on email, let me solve it and get back to you.

Comment: @Reena its okay, you welcome, if above code working fine then please accept and upvote and happy coding!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize strId in getView()

here in the following code, its not able to initialize it based on "view" object, hence you get nullpointer.

```
case R.id.imgLike:
    strId = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtId));
```

mark as solved if you find the answer useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
strId = (TextView) view.getParent().findViewById(R.id.txtId);
```

This will fix your crash, but you need to rethink about your design.

Answer (score 1):

**What u have to do is set Diff onclick Listeners on diff views**

```
viewHolder.txtDescription.setTag(R.id.txtDescription,position);
viewHolder.txtDescription.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position_clicked=(Integer)v.getTag();               
    }
});
```

**repeat it for every view your want to set listener**

Comment: I am using int position_clicked=(Integer)v.getTag();But It gives Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: setTag(R.id.txtDescription,position) use this for every view ,use R.id.txtDescription (i.e id of every view as key )

Comment: Plz help me. I using the  viewHolder.imgMyNewsFeedLike.setTag(R.id.imgMyNewsFeedLike,position);  viewHolder.imgMyNewsFeedLike.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {@Override
public void onClick(View v) {    
int position_clicked=(Integer)v.getTag();     System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!id====="+position_clicked);}
   }); Its Give Null Pointer Exception. And I am using this inside View getView() Method.

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.my_list_item, null);
        /** initialize ViewHolder */
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        /** Initialize Widgets */
        /** Imageview */

        viewHolder.imgLike = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imgLike);
        viewHolder.imgLike.setOnClickListener(this);
        viewHolder.imgLike.setTag(position);

        viewHolder.imgComments = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imgComments);
        viewHolder.imgComments.setOnClickListener(this);

        viewHolder.imgShare = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imgShare);
        viewHolder.imgShare.setOnClickListener(this);

        /** TextView */
        viewHolder.txtId = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtId);

        viewHolder.txtDescription = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);

        getData = arr.get(position);
        viewHolder.txtId.setText(getData
                .get(Fragment1.TAG_ID));

        viewHolder.txtDescription.setText(getData
                .get(Fragment1.TAG_MESSAGE));

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {               

        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.imgLike:

        View view = listview.getAdapter().getView(((ImageView)v).getTag(), null, listview);
            txtId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtId);

            System.out.println("On Click====="
                    + strId.getText().toString());

            urlLike = "http://www.example.com?id="
                    + strId.getText().toString() + "&user_id="
                    + myDetail.getUserId();

            new sendLikeData().execute();

            break;
        case R.id.imgComments:

            break;
        case R.id.imgShare:

            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Pratt, I am using  strId = ((TextView)v); then give the error like java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

Comment: @Akash Where is Declare listview in Adapter Class?

Comment: put you adapter in your list class from there you can get listview

Comment: View view = listview.getAdapter().getView(((ImageView)v).getTag(), null, listview); in this how to get listview?

Comment: just put your adapter code in your main class where you have declared ListView

Comment: @Akash I Put the Adapter Class in main Class then getView Convert into Integer. How to it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use onClickListener inside your adapter class.

Look this sample code

```
viewHolder.imgLike = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgLike);
viewHolder.imgLike.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String id = getData.get(Fragment1.TAG_ID);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am this But Its again get NullPointerException